# JUnit test case for static block in java

Tags: java, junit

can anyone tell how to do unit test for static block in java using junit powermockito api.

i tried using @beforeClass method where partially done.
faced issue while creating new object inside static block as PowerMockito.whenNew(----).thenReturn(mockedObjh) didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Just instantiate the class, then check if the changes to the values your static block should set/alter have been done

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this way**

```
@Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(TestStatickBlock.class); 

    }
    // mock all static methods
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(TestStatickBlock.class);  // try to use mockStatic
```